# Pyparsing getName() returns wrong name

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm parsing strings with `dotted.strings` and infix math operators. The parsing itself seems to work fine, but the name returned by `getName` is not what I expect.

```
from pyparsing import (Word, alphas, opAssoc, infixNotation, 
                       Suppress, Group, delimitedList, oneOf)
LPAR, RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")

chars = Word(alphas + "_")
colstr = Group(delimitedList(chars, delim=".")).setResultsName("colstr*")
infix_expr = infixNotation(colstr, [
    ("-", 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
    (oneOf("* /"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (oneOf("+ -"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
])("infix")
```

Now testing it out...

```
>>> infix_ex = infix_expr.parseString('a.b + x.y')
>>> print(infix_ex.dump())
[[['a', 'b'], '+', ['x', 'y']]]
- infix: [['a', 'b'], '+', ['x', 'y']]
  - colstr: [['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y']]
    [0]:
      ['a', 'b']
    [1]:
      ['x', 'y']
```

This is what I expect, but `getName` seems to return the name from the wrong level of the parsing tree.

```
>>> infix_ex.getName()
'infix'
>>> infix_ex[0].getName()
'colstr'
>>> infix_ex[0].asList()
[['a', 'b'], '+', ['x', 'y']]
```

As you can see, `getName` returns 'infix' for the root level and 'colstr' for the 'infix' level of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much unavoidable, since `getName()` is a method that is defined on `ParseResults`, not on the matched token (which could be a string, and thereby not supporting `getName()`).

Here is the example from the `ParseResults.getName` docstring:

```
    integer = Word(nums)
    ssn_expr = Regex(r"\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d")
    house_number_expr = Suppress('#') + Word(nums, alphanums)
    user_data = (Group(house_number_expr)("house_number")
                | Group(ssn_expr)("ssn")
                | Group(integer)("age"))
    user_info = OneOrMore(user_data)

    result = user_info.parseString("22 111-22-3333 #221B")
    print(result.asList())
    for item in result:
        print(item.getName(), ':', item[0])
```

Which prints:

```
[['22'], ['111-22-3333'], ['221B']]
age : 22
ssn : 111-22-3333
house_number : 221B
```

Note that, to use `getName()` each of the named bit has to be a `Group`, and that the name goes on the container, not on the matched token directly.

You *can* define results names on elements that are not `Group`s, and access them directly without having to get the `[0]`th element, but you would not be able to call `getName()` on them.

If you are planning to use `getName()` to walk the structure returned by parsing using `infixNotation`, I encourage you to instead define your own container classes for the operand and for each precedence level in your infix notation grammar. See the `simple_bool.py` example code to see how this is done. That way you will have more direct control over the objects passed back to you from pyparsing, rather than trying to work through the parsed infix notation hierarchy (and probably re-trace some parsing steps in the process).